# Get name of Mapbox POI

Tags: android, ios, react-native, openstreetmap, mapbox

I'm using Mapboox Streets for a project (react-native). I would like to show the name of the POI a user clicks on. I have got this to work fine when user has zoomed in enough by using the endpoint /v4/{map_id}/tilequery/{lon},{lat}.json

This gives me the features near where the user clicked. However, when zoomed out a bit there can be several POI's (some not even rendered) that are given as the response from the endpoint. I'm sure the best solution would be to use queryRenderedFeaturesAtPoint() but i'm not sure how this works without having the layers stored.

How can I make this more specific?